# Handling large dense matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix, 32-bit, python-2.6, windows-xp

Basically, what is the best way to go about storing and using dense matrices in python?

I have a project that generates similarity metrics between every item in an array.

Each item is a custom class, and stores a pointer to the other class and a number representing it's "closeness" to that class.

Right now, it works brilliantly up to about ~8000 items, after which it fails with a out-of-memory error.
Basically, if you assume that each comparison uses ~30 (seems accurate based on testing) bytes to store the similarity, that means the total required memory is:
`numItems^2 * itemSize = Memory`
So the memory usage is exponential based on the number of items.
In my case, the memory size is ~30 bytes per link, so:
`8000 * 8000 * 30 = 1,920,000,000 bytes, or 1.9 GB`
which is right at the memory limit for a single thread.

It seems to me that there has to be a more effective way of doing this. I've looked at memmapping, but it's already computationally intensive just to generate the similarity values, and bottlenecking it all through a harddrive seems a little ridiculous.

**Edit**
I've looked at numpy and scipy. Unfortunatly, they don't support very large arrays either.

```
>>> np.zeros((20000,20000), dtype=np.uint16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>>
```

**Further Edit**
Numpy seems to be popular. However, numpy won't really do what I want, at least without another abstraction layer.

I don't *want* to store numbers, I want to store reference to classes. Numpy supports objects, but that doesn't really address the array size issues. I brought up numpy just as an example of what *isn't* working.

Any advice?

**Edit** Well, I wound up just rewriting all the logic so it no longer stores any redundant values, reducing the memory useage from `O*n^2` to `O*((n*(n-1))/2)`.

Basically, this whole affair is a version of the [handshake problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake_problem), so I've switched from storing all links to only a single version of each link.

It's not a complete solution, but I generally don't have any datasets large enough to overflow it, so I think it will work out. PyTables is really interesting, but I don't know any SQL, and there doesn't appear to be any nice traditional slicing or index based way to access the table data. I may revisit the issue in the future.

Comment: Hmmm. Just found PyTables(http://www.pytables.org/). It looks promising

Comment: Care to post it as an answer? Seens to be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) can handle tables of arbitrary size (Millions of columns!), through using memmap and some clever compression.

Ostensibly, it provides SQL like performance, to python. It will, however, require significant code modifications.

I'm not going to accept this answer until I've done a more thorough vetting, to ensure it can actually do what I want. Or someone provides a better solution.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I've found my solution:
[h5py](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215002454/http://code.google.com:80/p/h5py/)

It's a library that basically presents a numpy-like interface, but uses compressed memmapped files to store arrays of arbitrary size (It's basically a wrapper for HDF5).

PyTables is built on it, and PyTables actually led me to it. However, I do not need any of the SQL functionality that is the main offering of PyTables, and PyTables does not provide the clean array-like interface I was really looking for.

h5py basically acts like a numpy array, and simply stores the data in a different format.

It also seems to have no limit to array size, except perhaps disk space. I'm currently doing testing on a 100,000 * 100,000 array of uint16.

Comment: 6 months later, I am wondering if you think h5py is still the ticket for using Python and numpy to operate on data that cannot fit into memory?

Comment: Really, I just haven't had a chance to look at this project much recently. Work interceded, and I have been a bit burnt-out recently, and thus not interested in working on personal projects.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you would not mind contacting me off line, I'd like to ask you some other questions about your experience using h5py as I am currently up against memory limits in my work and need a Python disk-based analytics option.

Comment: I'm not sure how much use my knowledge would be, but I'm lemuix AT imaginaryindustries DOT com , or fake--name on skype. I don't pretend to be an expert, but I managed to make h5py work (at least a little bit). Feel free to contact me.

Comment: What if I want to access whole matrix to give input to a function of size 57600 by 57600 of double?

Comment: @user3515225 - I don't believe h5py types will work as function parameters unless the function specifically knows how to use them. In this case, I'd suggest just going 64 bit, if needed. I can't think of a good reason to be developing 32 bit x86 code at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For the 20,000 x 20,000 you are looking at 12GB of RAM?

Aren't you going to end up in swap hell trying to work with a 12GB in win32 which artificially limits the memory that the OS can address?

I'd be looking for an OS that can support the 12GB (32 bin win 2003 server can if you need to stick with 32bit windows), but a 64 bit machine with 64bit OS and 16GB of RAM would seem a better fit.

Good excuse for an upgrade :)

64 bit numpy can support your matrix

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 20 2010, 23:14:04) 
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((20000,20000),dtype=np.uint16)
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: You don't end up in swap-hell, python just dies, either with a memory error, or silently. I'm asking because I can't believe no one has had a similar issue, and tried to solve it on 32 bit.

Comment: @Fake Name, swap hell will happen if you try to use 12GB of data with a kernel that is limited to 2 or 3GB of RAM whichever way you try to do it. Most likely noone has tried to solve it on 32 bit is because it is much more practical to use a 64 bit machine with sufficient RAM

Comment: (late response) No, you don't end up in swap hell, python crashes with an out of memory error. It never hits the swapfile.

Comment: @Fake, I meant if you try to operate on the 12GB of data while only having a small part of it in your process memory at a time. swapping would need to be managed by your process (since you exceed the addressable memory of the process) either something you write yourself or something provided by an abstraction such as an ORM

Comment: Ah, yeah. I really wouldn't want to have to write my own swap-system. As it is, a compresses memmapped array seems to work well enough. I'm CPU limited, not IO limited.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some advice in the [NumPy (see SciPy)](https://scipy.org/) documentation (arrays/matrices):

- [Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)
- [Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)

Comment: Nope - Fortunately, Numpy has the same array size limitations as I've already described.

Answer (score 0):

If you have N objects, kept in a list L, and you wish to store the similarity betwen each object and each other object, that's `O(N**2)` similarities. Under the common conditions that `similarity(A, B) == similarity(B, A)` and `similarity(A, A) == 0`, all that you need is a triangular array S of similarities. The number of elements in that array will be `N*(N-1)//2`. You should be able to use an array.array for this purpose. Keeping your similarity as a float will take only 8 bytes. If you can represent your similarity as an integer in `range(256)`, you use an unsigned byte as the array.array element.

So that's about 8000 * 8000 / 2 * 8 i.e. about 256 MB. Using only a byte for the similarity means only 32 MB. You could avoid the slow `S[i*N-i*(i+1)//2+j]` index calculation of the triangle thingie by simulating a square array instead using S[i*N+j]`; memory would double to (512 MB for float, 64 MB for byte).

If the above doesn't suit you, then perhaps you could explain """Each item [in which container?] is a custom class, and stores a pointer to the other class and a number representing it's "closeness" to that class."" and """I don't want to store numbers, I want to store reference to classes""". Even after replacing "class(es)" by "object(s)", I'm struggling to understand what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the memory use by using uint8, but be careful to avoid overflow errors. A uint16 requires two bytes, so the minimal memory requirement in your example is  8000*8000*30*2 bytes = 3.84 Gb.

If the second example fails then you need a new machine. The memory requirement is 20000*20000*2*bytes =800 Mb.

My advice is that you try to create smaller matrices and use "top", "ps v" or the gnome system monitor to check  the memory used by your python proces. Start out examining a single thread with a small matrix and do the math. Note that you can release the memory of a variable x by writing del(x). This is useful for testing.

What is the memory on your machine? How much memory does pytables use to create a 20000*20000 table? How much memory does numpy use to create a 20000*20000 table using uint8?

Comment: Also, you can't use a uint8 as a reference to a position in a table with 20000 rows, so the choice of uint16 was carefully calculated.

Comment: The problems might be caused by a 32 bit windows limitation:

"First, the 32-bit Python interpreter can only use 2 GB of your memory. Second, numpy arrays need a contiguous, un-fragmented, range of memory to be available within that 2 GB address space." (Quoted from http://old.nabble.com/Summation-of-large-float32-float64-arrays-td28638607.html )

I think that you can force numpy to use non-contiguous (c-style) arrays, but that will not remove the 2Gb memory limit.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to stop using windows 32. You may wish to have a look at the flag named IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE, but I don't know if that is safe to use. Here is a description of Microsoft memory limits:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx