# Operations on huge dense matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

For the purpose of training a neural network, at some point I have a huge 212,243 × 2500 dense matrix `phi`, and vectors `y` (212243) and `w` (2500), which are stored as `numpy` arrays of doubles. What I'm trying to compute is

```
w = dot(pinv(phi), y)
# serialize w...
r = dot(w, transpose(phi))
# serialize r...
```

My machine has 6 GB of RAM and 16 GB of swap on Ubuntu x64. I started the computation twice and twice it has ended with system (not python) swap errors after about an hour of work.

Is there a way I perform this computation on my computer? It doesn't need to be done with python.

Comment: You should check [h5py](https://code.google.com/p/h5py/). This was previously proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3315055/1258806, which answers a similar question.

Comment: Works for me. Took only a few minutes on a decent system: Python 3.3 64 bit, numpy-MKL 1.7.1, Core i7, 32 GB RAM, Windows 8.

Comment: Similar to what fgb says, you can try [Pytables](http://www.pytables.org/).  They both use the same underlying technology (HDF and numpy iirc)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the pseudoinverse for anything else than for computing `w`, replace that line with:

```
w = np.linalg.lstsq(phi, y)[0]
```

On my system it runs about 2x faster, and uses about half the intermediate storage.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
212,243 row values * 2500 col values * 8 bytes/value = 4,244,860,000 bytes = 4GB
```

That's how much memory you need to hold the whole matrix in memory.

If this were Java, I'd recommend that you bump up the max heap on your JVM. I don't know what the analogy for Python is.

Comment: But where would you store the intermediate result of the pseudoinverse that's computed as part of the dot product if 2/3 of your RAM is taken by `phi`?